# Data Mapping Between Excel Files and Third Part Applications

Tags: vba, excel, mapping

I'm working on a macro which named "*MasterTool*". All of macro code will be in this "*MasterTool*". This tool's main role is taking value of certain string name from excel sheet (input sheet) and write this values another excel sheet (output sheet) for same string name.

Additionally there's 2 different term I would like to describe you from now to understand easily.

- **Input Sheet**
  Excel file which stores some specific informations (E.g. `Vehicle Height` : `3m` ) ( One of the cell has my string value: `Vehicle Height` and adjacent next cell has it's value `3m` )
- **Output Sheet**
  This is also an excel sheet like report page which contains also specification information which comes from Input Sheet.

I wonder is it common usage data mapping methods in Excel VBA ?

**My first attempt is:**
Naming cells in Input Sheet like that: `strCellVehicleHeight` and I'm writing string name: `Vehicle Height`, also naming cell of this feature's value `strCellVehicleHeightValue` and I'm writing `3`.

On output sheet I named cells same and then mapping via cell names. It's a bit hard way to use I think.

Isn't there more possible ways or other formats like XML JSON etc. I would be glad if you help me about this situation.

Comment: (1) Please add your code ([edit]) you already have to your question, so we can help you directly on your own code. (2) What is your actual question? Because questions about how to implement something are off-topic;  you will only get opinion based answers which isn't really helpful.

Comment: @Peh thank you for your edit. It's first of all opinion based after i worked on it i can share. I'm looking for starting point my first attempt is not wise choice i think.

Comment: Yes the problem is I think there is not *the right one* answer. Asking for "*how to implement something*" is very opinion based and therefore off-topic: "*Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise. (from help)*" I mean you can do this "*this way*" or "*that way*" or "*another way*" there will be many solutions depending on your personal opinion. Asking for opinions is off-topic here. So you should ask something specific.

Comment: @Peh You're right but personally i want your recommendation; Is Stack Exchange has one of site for this type of questions ?

Comment: @Hakan: You can build applications based on JSON, here is the beginnings of one http://exceldevelopmentplatform.blogspot.com/2018/01/vba-parsed-json-as-application-state.html

Comment: @SMeaden thank you for your suggestion, that's what I am looking for.